# difference between paged page table and hierarchical paging

Tags: memory, page-tables

There is a paragraph in ComputerOrganizationAndDesign 5thEdition explore the problem that large size of the table "Most modern systems also allow the page tables to be paged, it works by using the same basic ideas of virtual memory and simply allowing the page tables to reside in the virtual address space."

What it's does is identical to hierarchical paging right? the table of hierarchical paging is point to the next level table, so it's also "the page tables to reside in the virtual memory space"?

But paged page and hierarchical paging are written separated, I can't figure out what's the different? does something missunderstanding?

Furthermore, the following mentioned about "never-ending series of page faults", I'm really can't understand..., what's the reason?

ref: ComputerOrganizationAndDesign 5thEdition

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add more related tags like 'cpu-architecture' to let more related experts see it and help you if they know the answer. Also, you better offer some contexts of the book to help quickly understanding of the problem.

In my COD risc-v, they are:

> 4. To reduce the actual main memory tied up in page tables, most
>    modern systems also allow the page tables to be paged. Although
>    this sounds tricky, it works by using the same basic ideas of virtual
>    memory and simply allowing the page tables to reside in the virtual
>    address space.

> 5. Multiple levels of page tables can *also* be used to reduce the total
>    amount of page table storage, and this is the solution that RISC-V
>    uses to reduce the memory footprint of address translation.

---

The following is my understanding when reading the COD. Please point out errors if some. Thanks.

---

From this [link](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4410/2015su/lectures/lec14-pagetables.html), I think they are just same.

And in my RISC-V version COD, it says:

> In brief, these problems are
> avoided by placing all the page tables in the address space of *the
> operating system* and placing at least some of the page tables for
> the operating system in a portion of *main memory* that is physically
> addressed and is *always present* and thus never in secondary
> memory.

So the 'never-ending series of page faults' will occur when the level 0 table (the terminology in the fifth of the indexed list) is located in secondary memory like disk or SSD. Although this condition is weird to occur.

---

With regard to why the author separate them, better to ask the author, although this is not practical in some way. (Maybe some students of the author can help doing that.)

I think the author want to highlight some 'small but critical problems', so he separate them into different paragraph.